# Search Cursor to apply summarize statistics to all the row in a column

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I use the following logic in ModelBuilder to get a result as seen below:

A feature class has a Column with the name "Value" which is passed through to the Summary Statistics Tools which calculates the Mean of the Column "Value".

The Get value tool then retrieves this from the summary table created and passes it to the calculate field tool. This one value is then added to all the row in the column named Mean.

[image: Model Builder Logic]

[image: Attribute Table]

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(outPRJ, r"C:/Users/dean/Desktop/Script Dependencies/03_Output/4_Stats/minValue.dbf",
                          [["Value", "MIN"]])

tableMin = r"C:/Users/dean/Desktop/Script Dependencies/03_Output/4_Stats/minValue.dbf"
fieldMin = ["MIN_Value"]
with arcpy.SearchCursor(tableMin, fieldMin) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        MinValue = print("MIN_Value: {}")


arcpy.CalculateFields_management(outPRJ, "Min", MinValue, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I want to use the same logic in a python script by using a search cursor and tried the code below which gives me an error. The Error received is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox Data/Dropbox/02_Agrimotion/ZZZ_Scripts/Chem Soil Interpolation - Updated Header Names.py", line 189, in <module>
    with arcpy.SearchCursor(tableMin, fieldMin) as cursor:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: What is the error, including line number, that you receive when running the code that you present?

Comment: The field Min_Value doesn't exist in what I presume is outPRJ per your screenshot above, so CalculateField_management won't be able to pass that. You likely need to perform a join and identify the fully qualified field name from the join, although it's unclear from the description and screenshot which field you'd be joining on. Please edit your question and images.

Comment: OK, I think I have a better understanding now. You want to populate the minimum value as calculated already in the `Statistics Analysis` which is based on one single column and does not vary based on another field. You want this same value to be added to every single row. You have already added a variable MinValue which holds this value from the (last row within the) minValue table. Instead of using `!Min_Value!` (a field name from a different table) in your calculate field, use `MinValue` (the variable created from `SearchCursor` code). @PolyGeo if you reopen I can add this as an answer.

Comment: The  ERROR 000800 makes me think you're using Pro (Python3) not Desktop. Although the option for "PYTHON_9.3" is supposed to be supported for backwards compatibility per their documentation, you can switch this to be "PYTHON3" or leave the option blank (Python is default in the version of arcpy that comes with ArcPro.)

Comment: @smiller This is exactly what I want to do and I can do it with Model Builder. Thank you for the suggestion of changing it too MinValue. Unfortunately it did not work. I've updated the code in the question to reflect this suggestion.

Comment: @smiller just to clarify, I am using Desktop 10.6. I assume it is the new form of searchcursor.da that is causing the issue. I have removed the .da and will report what the error says

Comment: What is the new error after making this change (to MinValue variable)? You did not update the error message to reflect the new code.Also the error has nothing to do with searchcursor, and in fact you should be using the da.searchCursor as the old version is deprecated (I believe as of 10.x)

Comment: @smiller Updated the error report in the Question. If I remove the .da it does not give me the ERROR 000800.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92050/discussion-between-smiller-and-dean-van-den-heever).

Comment: Again I recommend not using the non-data access module version of SearchCursor, because it is no longer supported and has been replaced by da.SearchCursor. Note that the error you receive now under SearchCursor is due to not having the expected parameters -- in SearchCursor fields is the 4th parameter, or you can pass as a named parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use da.SearchCursor to store all values in a list. Then use pythons built in functions to find min, max and mean (sum and len(gth)). Write values to the attribute table using da.UpdateCursor.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\database.fgdb\featureclass' #Change
valuefield = 'Value' #Change
new_fields = ['min','max','mean'] #Change

for field in new_fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=fc, field_name=field, field_type='DOUBLE')

all_values = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,valuefield)]

minval = min(all_values)
maxval = max(all_values)
meanval = sum(all_values)/len(all_values)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, new_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=minval
        row[1]=maxval
        row[2]=meanval
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a better experience with UpdateCursor as outlined by BERA, but to answer your initial question using CalculateField:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(outPRJ, r"C:/Users/dean/Desktop/Script Dependencies/03_Output/4_Stats/minValue.dbf",
                          [["Value", "MIN"]])

tableMin = r"C:/Users/dean/Desktop/Script Dependencies/03_Output/4_Stats/minValue.dbf"
fieldMin = ["MIN_Value"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tableMin, [fieldMin]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        MinValue = row[0] 


arcpy.CalculateField_management(outPRJ, "Min", MinValue, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

A few notes:

1. I recommend not using the non-data access module version of SearchCursor, because it is no longer supported and has been replaced by da.SearchCursor. Note that the error you receive now under SearchCursor is due to not having the expected parameters -- in SearchCursor fields is the 4th parameter, or you can pass as a named parameter, e.g. arcpy.SearchCursor(tableMin, fields=fieldMin).  See http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/searchcursor.htm for more information on this (old) tool.
2. If CalculateField_management (note: changed from your code which had CalculateFields - plural) does not work, double-check the error and use either "PYTHON", "PYTHON_9.3" per http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm
3. I assume that the variable MinValue will be able to pass due to code examples here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm. If not, another way is to join the tables and reference by column name.